# onCreateDialog() not taking two cases

Tags: android

I want to display timePicker 2 times. for retriving start time n for stop time. THis code is showing error as "Duplicate case". I tried alot but am unable to find answer for this silly question. Please guide me.

```
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
 {
    switch (id) 
    {
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID1:
      //  return new TimePickerDialog(this,
           //   mTimeSetListener, startHour, startMinute, true);
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hr:"+startHour+"min:"+startMinute, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID2:
        //  return new TimePickerDialog(this,
             //   mTimeSetListener, startHour, startMinute, true);
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hr:"+stopHour+"min:"+startMinute, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    }
    return null;
 }
```

Comment: What are the values of TIME_DIALOG_ID1 and TIME_DIALOG_ID2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you defined those two constants to have the same value.  They need different values.

Comment: Yes. U are right. Such a silly mistake. Thanks. I am accepting your answer.